# How to read bytes as stream in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a binary file (ogg vorbis) and extracting some packets for later processing. These packets are python bytes objects, and would we useful read them with a "read(n_bytes)" method. Now my code is something like this:

```
packet = b'abcd'
some_value = packet[0:2]
other_value = packet[2:4]
```

And I want something like this:

```
packet = b'abcd'
some_value = packet.read(2)
other_value = packet.read(2)
```

How can I create a readable stream from a bytes object?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use a `io.BytesIO` file-like object

```
>>> import io
>>> file = io.BytesIO(b'this is a byte string')
>>> file.read(2)
b'th'
>>> file.read(2)
b'is'
```